# Asynchronous Programming Model in WCF with async/await - Runtime Error on Serialization

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I developed my code based on this posting : 
**[Asynchronous Programming Model in WCF with async/await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx)**

There was **no compilation error** but when hosted it generates below specified error :

Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consid
er marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its m
embers you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type
is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.
See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

What could be the reason for this.

Comment: Does any of your data contract have the new Task\Task<K> class as datamember? 
Async tasks are new in WCF, and available through the Async CTP release for WCF. Look at sample provided as part of CTP to understand how it is working.
But going by the error the WCF framework is trying to serialize a Task class which is not meant to be serialize.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I would like to attach the code segment which would be easy to understand. I do not return a datacontract oject just returning the Task<string>. method --------- public async Task<string> HelloAsync(string name) { return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "hello " + name); } ---------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your methods is either returning a Task object, or has a Task object as one of its parameters.

Tasks cannot be passed across the web-service boundary - this is the cause of your problem.

**Update:** I had a look at the link you got this code from, and it looks like the code provided is conceptual only.  If you look closely at the wording, he says 'will' instead of 'can'.

> WCF **vNext** will adopt the Async model
>   in both the client and the server
>   side, and provide new Task-based
>   overloads for some of the most used
>   asynchronous APIs.

Since a Task cannot be passed over the web-service boundary, it will not work.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply. I have attached the code segment which does not return the task object.                                                      public class HelloService : IServiceContract
    {
        public async Task<string> HelloAsync(string name)
        {
            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "hello " + name);
        }
    }

Comment: I have not modified any of the code given in the example  Asynchronous Programming Model in WCF with async/await http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx so how could i get the error